# Adding second HDD (SSD)

Tags: partition, hard-disk, ssd

Having a laptop with 240GB SSD, and I removed my dvd drive to put a second SSD (240GB) in DVD slot.

I see my second SSD in the BIOS, also in my file manager in Debian, but when I click on it, it does nothing, as option with ''right click mouse'' I see ''mount'' but I get an error `fail to mount 240GB volume - no object for D-bus interface`.

I've already formatted and partitioned it (GPT and Ext4). So now, I don't know what to do to use it?

Idea?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Here solution for me, we can close.

EDIT: So now I have acces to open it with those commands ;

```
sudo mkdir /media/HDD
sudo mount /dev/sda /media/HDD
```

but it is as ''root'' so I can't create a new folder or something like that.

EDIT2: Got it with;

```
sudo chown -R james:james /media/HDD
```

Comment: You should not use sda, but create & format a partition like sda1. Many tools expect partitions and will complain. And you now have what is called a SuperFloppy as the old floppy drives were small & did not have partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do (try) all this steps: expecially create the mouint Point

https://www.debiantutorials.com/how-to-add-a-new-hard-disk-or-partition-using-uuid-and-ext4-filesystem/

ls -la /etc/fstab

-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 594 Okt 27 15:40 /etc/fstab

Put the uuid manuelly in: sudo gedit /etc/fstab

Comment: not with CLI but I used GPARTED

Comment: I tried it final with your link, but got errors;

`sudo mount /disk2
mount: /disk2: can't find in /etc/fstab.

~$ sudo echo "UUID=d8c45458-57fc-43e6-92ea-ab4644fd6682 /disk2 ext4  errors=remount-ro 0 1" >> /etc/fstab
bash: /etc/fstab: Permission denied`

Comment: step 6 should have put it in your fstab; nor errormessage when you did?

Comment: it does not work, I got error during that step, so nothing is in etc/fstab